# Docker: Run command while another command is running

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to configure a program running in a docker container. To achieve that the program must be running (and provide an open port) so that the administration program can connect to the running process. Unfortunately there is no simple editable config file so this is the only way. The RUN command is obviously not the right one because it does not provide a running instance after docker went to the next command. The best way would be doing this while building the docker image but if it has to be done during container start it would be OK as well. But there is (as far as I know) also no easy way to run multiple commands on startup. Does anyone has an idea how to do that?

To make it a bit more clear, here is a simple example from my Dockerfile:

```
# this command should start the application which has to be configured
RUN /usr/local/server/server.sh
# I tried this command alternatively because the shell script is blocking
RUN nohup /usr/local/server/server.sh &

# this is the command which starts an administration program which connects to the running instance started above
RUN /usr/local/administration/adm [some configuration parameters...]

# afterwards the server process can be stopped
```

Downloading the complete program directory containing the correct state could be a solution, too. But then the configuration cannot changed easily in the Dockerfile, what would be great.

Answer (score 0):

A Dockerfile is supposed to be a sequential list of instructions to produce an image. The image should contain your application's code, and all of its installable dependencies.

Each RUN instruction gets executed as its own container. Once the command that you run completes, any changed files get committed as a new image layer.

Trying to run a process in the background, will cause the command you are running to return immediately. Once that happens, the container is considered stopped, and the Dockerfile's next instruction will be executed in a new separate container.

If you really need two processes running, you will need to produce a command that you can pass to a single RUN instruction.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote a shell script now and run it as it is only one command. This seems to work